# Direct URL to local file via the host file

Tags: hosts-file

I know I can map URLs to other URLs via the host file, but can I map a URL to a local html file on my hard drive **without** running a local server and loading the html file through there? Something like:

```
C:\myTestFile.html    www.google.com
```

I'd like to know how to do this on both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Actually, you're not mapping URLs at all. You're just resolving a hostname.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you actually want to display a certain HTML page when attempting to access Google or do you just want to display a local HTML file in your browser?

Comment: @ckhan thx. i'm not suprised that my vocab was off on this one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you cannot.

The hosts file is for mapping **hostnames** to **IP addresses** (and not "URLs"), especially when a DNS Server is not available or when there's a need to override entries in a DNS server.

A file has no hostname/IP address, thus, what you're asking is not possible.

If you want to read more on this subject:

- [hosts file (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)
- [The Hosts File and what it can do for you](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/hosts-files-explained/)

Comment: Thanks for both answering my question and helping clear up my vocab ;)

Answer (score 0):

actually you can very easily, all you have to do is start a local webserver and include your local html in said server. that way when you redirect to 127.0.0.1, your "local file" is displayed. this can be used as a parental control feature or a way of blocking certain websites on company computers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question specifically states "without running a local server".